# linux library for constructing EAPOL frames, especially Supplicant Responses

Tags: linux, wireless

I am in a project to develop an 802.11 wireless chip and have been tasked with updating our 802.11 test suite to incorporate 802.1X encryption.

The first tests will be using the chip in Station mode, and the setup will use a 3rd party AP and a RADIUS server. (The tests are run via scripts which act as the bulk of an 802.11 "driver", with a thin kernel driver layer beneath, and I have no involvement with the latter.)

Now have a fair grasp of how 802.1X works and the format of EAPOL frames etc, I feel I can avoid a lot of wheel reinventing and fiddly coding of key transformations etc by finding an up-to-date C library or command line interface that the script controlling the DUT Station can supply with a raw EAPOL Request frame (in hex for example), along with the PMK and any other required input, such as IEs, and have it output a raw response frame which my script can then output to the Station for forwarding to the AP as the EAPOL Response.

This code/interface need not in fact must not go as far as trying to receive or send frames itself. As I say, it should be merely a convenience mechanism for constructing EAPOL frames.

(I may later need to test the wireless chip in encrypted AP mode. So it would be handy if the interface could also work on the other side of the fence and output EAPOL Request frames that an AP would send to a Supplicant.)

Any constructive suggestions gratefully received.

The wpa_supplicant suite, at http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/ looks excellent, bang up to date and with complete coverage. But it isn't clear whether, and if so how, it can be used in the limited manner explained above rather than taking over the whole connection.